# Python - How to create an array from a sql command with just the values?

Tags: python, sql, arrays

I want to create an array from the data I got from my database.

My database looks something like this:

```
name, age, height, birth_month
John, 57,  2.11,   April 
Rico, 57,  1.05,   June 
Max,  57,  1.50,   December 
Lisa, 35,  1.23,   July 
Beth, 21,  1.66,   July 
Luna, 89,  2.3,    July`
```

Now I want an array excluding `name` and putting `birth_month` first.
Here is the array I want to create:

```
data = [[April,     57,  2.11],
        [June,      57,  1.05],
        [December,  57,  1.50],
        [July,      35,  1.23],
        [July,      21,  1.66],
        [July,      89,  2.3 ]]
```

So what I tried to do was this:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT birth_month, age, height FROM customers")
print(mycursor.fetchall())
```

But this is not exactly what I want. How can I get an array formatted, just as I want?

This is what I get:

```
[[(u'April', Decimal('57'), Decimal('2.11')),
(u'June', Decimal('57'), Decimal('1.05')),
(u'December', Decimal('57'), Decimal('1.50')),
(u'July', Decimal('35'), Decimal('1.23')),
(u'July', Decimal('21'), Decimal('1.66')),
(u'July', Decimal('89'), Decimal('2.3'))]]
```

What I want is that the "Decimal" and "u'" dissapears, and that every row has seperate [].

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the output you get is different from what you want?

Comment: I added my result to the question below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name,age,height FROM customers")
print(mycursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: I also want to remove the u' and Decimal()

Comment: those arent really there ... its just a representation `print(u"hello")` or `print(Decimal("1.0"))`

Comment: So the array that I get is correct, with what I want?

Comment: probably ... its the values that you want ... but if you are submitting it to an autograder or something you might need to finesse the data a tiny bit more

Comment: I want to use it in formulas like y = x + Variable. Does it work?

Comment: `Decimal("1.5") + 3` gives you what? `u"hello"+" bob"` is also easy to test ... it probably took longer to add your comment than to just try it  (in otherwords yes you should be able to work just fine with these values)

Comment: I can't use those values, because if I use data[1]. It takes the month and lenght with it!

Comment: How can I split them up, I am a beginner with python arrays

Comment: data[0] is the 0th row... `data[0][0]` is the 0th element(month) of the 0th row, `data[0][1]` would be the 1st element(age?) of the 0th row... etc

Comment: Im curious why you are doing this? it seems like you have a pretty significant skills gap to be able to be successful at this task... is this for a school project that you can work with a teacher or mentor on? or is this for a job? in which case they should really bring someone on that has these skills ... of coarse if this is just a fun side project you are working on thats fine too... but you might want to do more basic python tutorials first